# Preventing directory traversal in nginx ingress in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, security, kubernetes, regex, nginx-ingress

I have the following ingress defined:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: someName
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "ingress-public"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "JSESSIONID"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/connection-proxy-header: "keep-alive"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      # block if not / or /test or /something
      if ($request_uri !~* "(^\/(?:(?:test|something)(?:\/|$)|$))") {
        return 404 ;
        break;
      }
      # redirect if proto_http
      if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        break;
      }

      # hsts required header
      add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: someservice
          servicePort: 80
```

The regex covers most cases where requests are something like `/config` - as this doesn't match the regex, it returns a 404.

There are two problems that I currently have.

1. Requesting `/test%2F..%2Fconfig` does NOT return a 404 even though this doesn't match the regex.
2. Requesting `/test/..%2Fconfig` allows you to reach `/config`.

So is there either a better regex that would cover these cases, or is there a way to convert `$request_uri` into an absolute uri so the regex can work on that instead of an encoded uri?

The regex is here with some test cases: https://regex101.com/r/Msu402/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try using a `location` ([doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)) or `$uri` ([doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri)) since both match a normalized URI. Since [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) I would suggest a location (untested):

```
location ~* ^/(?!test|something) {
  return 404;
}
```

Edit: I reread your question and it should BLOCK access to the mentioned locations in the regex. So I added the "not"...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try using `location` before but the issue was that I was using `!~*` instead of `~*`, and now know you can only using to match things not for things that don't match. And also I was missing a `;` after the return and the online config checker I was using didn't point that out :(
Seems to be working well now